# R statistical language on Visual studio

Tags: r, visual-studio-2012, mathematical-optimization

I am a newbie in Machine learning and Statistics. As I used opencv for my project(which I used in visual studio) and wanted to perform basis persuit operation, which is difficult to perform. So, I searched and took opinions of expert to get efficient programming library based on c++(I am from electronics background and c++ knowledge is more than sufficient).I have got information that you can build R programs on eclipse>

Can you please suggest me some references for running R on visual studio??

Does Rcpp runs on Visual studio?

Comment: Sorry for asking such a low research problem.I am a newbie in Machine learning and Statistics. As I used opencv for my project(which I used in visual studio) and wanted to perform basis persuit operation, which is difficult to perform. So, I searched and took opinions of expert to get efficient programming library based on c++(I am from electronics background and c++ knowledge is more than sufficient).I have got information that you can build R programs on eclipse,So just checking if it is available for visual studio or anyone has any other method to work on it.Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is answer with source:

```
2.9 Can I use Rcpp with Visual Studio ?
Not a chance.
And that is not because we are meanies but because R and Visual Studio simply
do not get along. As Rcpp is all about
extending R with C++ interfaces, we are bound by the available toolchain. 
And R simply does not compile with Visual Studio.
```

Source: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf

Comment: Thanks for quoting from the FAQ. There was a reason we wrote that...

Comment: @Jatin: Thanks for the answer.Can you suggest me a library which I can used on visual studio for Convex programming for MAchine learning?? I am working on kernels in Machine learning